# tinybutstrong not showing special characters from mysql

Tags: mysql, tinybutstrong

I'm trying to load data from a MySQL DB from a varchar(35) / utf8_swedish_ci field through TBS (tinybutstrong) and PHP using the example ([MySQL data merge](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/examples.php?e=datamysql&m=template)). My issue is that data loads fine if only ascii characters are in the fields but as soon as I add a single scandinavian special character like ö or ä the field contents vanishes entirely and other fields in row display correctly.

My understanding is that the latest versions on TBS automatically use UTF-8 coding (I have 3.9.0 for PHP 5) so I assumed it would work out-of-the-box. To be safe, I even added the coding to template as so:

'$TBS->LoadTemplate('mysql.html','UTF-8');' but to no avail.

Could someone please advice what is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a good UTF-8 processing, all elements of the chain must be UTF-8.

You have to ensure that your template is UTF-8 : check the entered text and the HTML element `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

You have to ensure that all your PHP scripts are UTF-8 and not Ansi.

You also have to ensure that your MySQL connection is set to receive UTF-8 queries and to return UTF-8 item data. This can be done for example by querying the SQL : `SET NAMES 'UTF8'`

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. Here's what I did:
In MySQL I ran 3 commands
- ALTER DATABASE stadinru_paivystaja CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;
- ALTER TABLE tilaus_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;
- ALTER TABLE tilaus_table MODIFY tilaus_custname VARCHAR(35) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;

In php I checked this setting is present:
My php.ini contains this: default_charset = "utf-8"


My template.html file contains <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Both files .php and .html have been edited under utf-8.

Comment: But still the scandic characters were not showing.\r
\r
Then finally I added the command mysql_query("set names 'utf8'"); into the php file and that helped, now the scandic characters are showing correctly. Thanks a lot!